# Many to one relationship not shown on find and toList in Linq to entities code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

hello im trying to build a rest api with many to one relationship using code first. here is my two entities :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RestApiAndForm.Models
{
    public class Categorie
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required,MaxLength(60)]
        public string nom { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Produit> produits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RestApiAndForm.Models
{
    public class Produit
    {
        
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required,Index,MaxLength(60)]
        public string libelle { get; set; }
        public uint stock;
        [Required]
        public Categorie categorie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is the context :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace RestApiAndForm.Models
{
    public class bdTestContext : DbContext
    {
        public bdTestContext() : base("connTest") { }
        public DbSet<Categorie> categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produit> produits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in my controller im using this code :

```
using RestApiAndForm.Models;
using RestApiAndForm.Models.Dto;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace RestApiAndForm.Controllers
{
    public class ProduitController : ApiController
    {
        private  bdTestContext bd = new bdTestContext();
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Produit> GetProduits()
        {
            try
            {
                List<ProduitResponse> produitResponses = new List<ProduitResponse>();
                List<Produit> produits = bd.produits.ToList();
                return produits;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

i want to get the product and there categorie but the entity does not come with the categorie information even when im using produit.Find(id) , i cant have access to the categorie entity.
this is the result on postman (as you can see all categorie are set to null )
[Postman result of the getProduits method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaXyc.png)
does anyone have the solution for that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include them like the following :

```
    List<Produit> produits = bd.produits.Include(p=> p.categorie).ToList();
```

Refer to : [Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

And don't forget to add
`using System.Data.Entity;` to your usings.

Comment: i have this error when i tried it ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type RestApiAndForm 
```

Comment: @Youtechcode add `using System.Data.Entity;` to your usings at the top of the file

Comment: @Youtechcode Welcome, do'nt forget to mark the answer as the right one.